# Can a private pilot refuel his small private airplane internationally without passing through immigration or customs?

Tags: airport, general-aviation, refueling, long-haul

I've been a private pilot for many years, but I have never flown internationally in small private aircraft. I'm about to buy a tiny, high-tech, super-efficient 2-seat airplane that has extended range fuel tanks that make it possible to fly 8000km == 5000 miles without refueling (24+ hours).  The longest flights necessary to cross the south-pacific in hops is 4000km (about 16 hours of flight at 250kph).

Such long range makes it possible for this tiny aircraft to fly anywhere on earth.  Nonetheless, I'd have to be nuts not to stop more often than every 16 hours when that is possible: for a meal, potty stop, walk around and stretch body & legs... and eventually sleep!

This raises the asked question.  Can a pilot, with or without one passenger, stop in other nations **JUST** to refuel without needing to go through immigration (and get a visa for that nation)... just to land, pull up to the gasoline pumps, fill them up, get back into the airplane, then fly away?

Note that this is NOT a question about flying in a commercial airplane on a conventional scheduled airplane flight. I also presume the stop will not involve going inside any building or leaving the refueling area within the private aircraft portion of the airport. It will involve getting out of the airplane, because refueling of diverse small private airplanes is generally done by hand by pilots, not by the huge trucks that fuel jet airplanes. Typically small airplanes just pull up to a pump much like you'd see at any gasoline station, insert credit card, pump fuel into the wings, then fly away.

When I get the airplane, after a month or two of getting used to it in north america, I plan to flying down to Chile with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 stops between (depending on these rules), then fly to dozens of islands in the south pacific (and land many places and islands that have airstrips, but no buildings (or at least no legal/government buildings).

In the later cases (south-pacific islands with tiny populations), I suspect nobody bothers or cares, because they assume all air traffic is strictly local. But flying down through (or 20 miles offshore) of Mexico through central America then Columbia, Ecuador, Peru and then finally into northern Chile (where I intend to spend a great deal of time) may be another matter entirely.

Comment: Range is 5000 miles? What airplane is that?

Comment: What's it use for fuel?

Comment: The airplane is a Pipistrel Virus SW with Rotax 912iS engine flown at "economy speed" (roughly 240kph).  At "cruise speed" (about 275kph), more like 4000 miles.  Of course you need to buy the optional 300 liter "extreme range tanks" too.  The engine runs on premium unleaded automobile gasoline (without ethanol).  Can accept ethanol, with a reduction of about 5% fuel economy.  It can also take standard aviation fuel (100LL), but best to avoid that for longest engine lifetime.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got 4000 miles from, at 100 liter tanks and maximum range is 767nm, with 300 liters it would be just over 2000nm. Keep in mind that's theoretical and you wouldn't in practice get that far as you'd need reserves.

Comment: Also, if you are landing at international airports for fuel avgas is what you're most likely to find, mogas is generally available at the more LSA friendly airfields, even then it can be hard to find.

Comment: @GdD : You must be looking at the wrong model or wrong engine.  Note that the other Rotax 912 engines are much less fuel efficient than the computerized fuel-injected Rotax 912iS (though both are 100HP).  Check the [link](http://forum.pipistrelowners.com) forum, the Virus and Virus SW section for the Virus SW100 real life performance message and you'll find the actual real-life experiences of real owners.  Note also that pilots of pipistrel virus sw aircraft have flown the 4000km "longest hop" across the south-pacific several times.  That is as real world as you can get.

Comment: @GdD : Yes, will need to research what fuel is available at what locations before leaving.  To get the best gasoline may well be a challenge, which is yet another reason having a very long range is quite helpful (more landing options).  To have contacts in advance at expected landing sites is helpful too... hopefully they can bring outside fuel to the airport [for "their" airplane].

Comment: I’m not sure but maybe your POH may contain figure of range. Can you post it when you get it?

Comment: I have the PDF document for the airplane, but it only gives information for 75% power "cruise speed" and maximums like Vne (302kph).  All information for "economy speed" comes from existing owners.  I have a friend who has one of these and gets 70+ mpg at her best economy speed (usually about 230kph~240kph at about 13,500 feet altitude).  For 75% power "cruise speed" and 100 liter regular size fuel tanks the PDF says 1550km range @ 275kph.  Extrapolate that to 300 liter tanks == 4650km range with nose-wheel version (or 4790km range my tail-wheel version).  But economy speed is **much** better.

Comment: @vasin1987 : I have the PDF, but don't see how to post PDF files here.  But the best information is in that forum.pipistrelowners.com forum in the "Virus and Virus SW" section in a topic title something like "real world performance".

Comment: You can screen capture it and post relevant page here.

Comment: I just looked at the formatting page and don't see how to make an image visible here without putting it on a webpage somewhere and linking to the image in the webpage.  Maybe I'm missing something.  Here, try clicking on the following internet link and see if you can download the PDF, then look on page 5:  </br>  https://www.pipistrel-usa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Pipistrel-VirusSWiS-Information-Pack.pdf

Comment: I would check with AOPA for the countries you are interested in landing in, and some intermediates as well in case of weather, mechanical problems, etc.  I have looked at www.skyvector.com for a flight down to Guadalupe, it shows airports and fuel availability & prices, so that might be another resources to check as well.  Looking at skyvector, a flight from southern Texas, KTX, Midvalley Airport, to SCDA, Diega Aracena, is 3227nm. I think I'd pick a route that didn't have such long stretches over water myself.  That's a long time in a small plane.

Comment: From the Pipestrel website:  While the performance numbers of the Virus SW do not change, as the 912 iS maintains 100 HP, the fuel consumption decreases dramatically by as much as 21%, preliminary numbers show. This means that the Virus SW equipped with the new Rotax 912 iS cruises at 274 km/h (147 kts) in 15 litres per hour (3.95 gph). What an amazing achievement! It can be said that the double NASA Challenge Winner Virus SW finally got the perfect engine!
3227nm/147kts = 22 hours in the air.  I'm pretty sure I couldn't do that and still be a good pilot.

Comment: @CrossRoads : That www.skyvector.com website is sweet.  Thanks for pointing that out to me.  Yes, I agree that a route that avoids open ocean is a better idea.  Even better that application lets me choose routes that pass over interesting terrain (mountains, lakes, etc).  I don't mind traveling 25% further and pay 25% more for fuel to fly over more interesting places and avoid open ocean.

Comment: @CrossRoads : The 912iS engine was improved a little further since that article, and they don't discuss the better fuel economy at "economy speed" which is about 240kph to 250kph versus cruise speed of 275kph.

Comment: only done that route ever in X-Plane and MSFS. Best bet is probably flying to Miami, then follow the Bahamas in the direction of the Dominican Republic and St.Maarten and to Guadeloupe from there. Lots of islands to put down in in case of emergency or to get something to eat and gas.

Answer (score 5):

While it depends on the country, expect to have mandatory immigration checks on first port of entry in most countries. I know this to be true for the US, Canada, Britain, Russia and the EU (Schengen area). Usually only emergency landings are exempt. But they may lead to investigations so not really an alternative to declare one in each and every country.

Usually it's best to hire a service provider to prepare all the paperwork for your trip. While their main business is to prepare commercial flights (non airliner), most also accept private pilots as clients, a few even welcome them. They will not just plan your journey regarding visas, landing and crossing permits (some countries do require preregistration for each and every flight into their territory), but also make sure to pick only airports with the right fuel available, or making it available. Selecting and booking hotels can be included as well.

Anyone I know, who ever tried to fly further than the next door country, sooner or later took such service as it makes a huge difference. Well, some had to make the experiance to get stuck for a week at some border first :))

Comment: first point of entry is the crux here. If you never enter the country you don't have a first point of entry. And staying on board or on the ramp while a crew refuels you may or may not count as entry depending on the country and facility. I've had fuel stops (albeit as a passenger) many times in various places, and rarely had to go through customs in the process. Can't see how it'd be different if you're a pilot and just waiting for someone to "fill her up".

Comment: Take the US as example. When entering, you're right away directed to the immigration apron. There's no fuel or whatsoever, and you're advised to stay inside your plane, even on a fricking hot day, until they done their way. The US is one of the countries even checking passengers between international flights - they always check. Canada is the same albeit a bit more relaxed. In the EU (and other countries) handling varies as sometimes most of the time you're allowed to leave the plane and wait in their office buildings or alike.

Comment: Can you list a few of those companies... or at least provide the generic name for those types of companies so I can perform a search?  You mentioned US, Canada, Britain, Russia, EU... but my flying will be US, Mexico, all the others in central America, then the western part of South America (Ecuador, Peru, Chile, western Bolivia and Argentina).  Hmmm, maybe overfly Columbia up at the north end before Ecuador.  Those companies should know, so try to tell me who they are and how to contact them.  Thanks for that tip.

Comment: Since I never flown in South America (nor Mexico) or Asia, I can't give reliable information here. General term would be _flight services_ or _flight support._ 
 Not sure if names are wellcome here, but examples might be World Air Ops in the US, FlightWorx in the UK or FSINT in Germany. While the former are more geared toward large customers, seams FSI quite willing to support everyone - at least I made good experiance when planing a world tour (which never hapened). There are many more, jsut do a web search, maybe with 'overflight permissions' as additional keywords.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the laws in the country you are landing in, but for the most part there's no reason you can't refuel without going through customs/passport control, commercial pilots do this all the time. They don't get out of the airplane for the most part but there's no reason they couldn't. Generally there's no reason to go through passport control unless you want to enter the general terminal area or exit the airport altogether.

Comment: That makes sense.  Would the pilot generally inform approach or tower the landing is for refueling only?  Also, would it be necessary to only refuel at POE (port of entry) airports?  Probably, huh?

Comment: When we fly from the Lower48 to Alaska, transiting Canada, the customs language from both countries specifically state to "not get out of the aircraft" until a customs official is present. This is most tricky when arriving in AK, where the most common first stop is Tok, which has no customs facility on-site, but to where customs agents will drive to from the border crossing when the flight is pre-coordinated. They state: "it is important to arrive as close as possible to your ETA, because you cannot exit the aircraft until we arrive."

Comment: @Jimmy : What if one flew into international airspace in Washington state, then re-entered in Alaska without entering Canada airspace?  Does that make anything easier?  Probably not, huh?  Nonetheless, fantastic if smaller airports in other nations do what you describe in TOK (Tok Junction Airport).

Comment: @bootstrap that happens all the time. "International Airspace" isn't the problem, nor is even flying through a foreign airspace. Most countries are part of ICAO, which have overflight agreements. Departing Chicago, flying over Canada, and landing in Anchorage, AK requires no customs upon arrival. It's only once you've had your boots on someone else's soil that the next country in line wants to talk to you upon entry.

Comment: @Jimmy : Obviously it makes sense that airplanes can fly over nations they won't land in without creating immigration / customs issue.  If that wasn't true, a great deal of travel by flying would be utterly intolerable.  From a similarly logical viewpoint, it makes sense that the runways, taxiways, aircraft fueling areas [and restroom] would be legally considered equivalent to "being up in the air" (overflying).  This would make stops for refueling nearly as non-problematic as overflying (from the standpoint of immigration and customs issues).  Maybe that's more-or-less how it works.  Thanks.

Comment: @bootstrap Nonetheless you may still need to get an approval ahead of flight time to cross over any country. Nations like to keep their airspace tidy, so even if you're intention is just to pass over, you need permission. Something not given en route at all (some special cases exist, but they are rather rare). So plan to get all fly over permits well before take off.