# Visa Requirements for GA

Tags: general-aviation, airport, refueling

I'm planning to take a flight in a small airplane around the world, which means I will have to stop to refuel in various countries. The countries I am particularly asking about are Turkey and Iran. If I just want to land and refuel, then takeoff again, without exiting the airport, will I still need a transit visa/customs clearance?

Comment: What country do you live in?

Comment: If planing this sort of trip, you do not ask strangers on the internet. You'd normally be working through service provider/s to support the flight https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/58917/60886 . Even if you can land somewhere to refuel without a Visa, having a plan for when something prevents you taking off would be pretty much mandatory anyway.

Comment: You could also check over at the travel.stackexchange.com, which has a very popular 'visas' tag for questions.

Comment: @tedder42 Due to various rules, it may be relevant not just what country you live in but what country you are a *citizen* of.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use a reputable FBO in those countries and work closely with them to identify all the requirements you will have to meet. Turkey is not a big deal, but for Iran you may also want to check with the US State Dept.